VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue:229 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "InvalidValueError: Map: Expected mapDiv of type HTMLElement but was passed null."
when the Internet is slow and you try to press the button to the Next page this error comes But if you leave a pause so that the button does not work yes Then quickly there will be a problem getting up will be slow I don’t know what to do I wanted to put onMounthed I think this is not the best solution

"I don’t know what to do" - start by reading [ask], please.
